# Extract just the service name and port number from tnsnames.ora file

Tags: regular-expression

I would like to give a ***service name***, and get a port number in return.

My tnsnames.ora file looks like:

```
DELUCA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = TCP.world)(PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = database.example.com.au)(Port = 32001))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = D10)
    )
  )

TOTAL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = TCP.world)(PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = database.example.com.au)(Port = 32002))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = D11)
    )
  )
FMAX =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = TCP.world)(PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = database.example.com.au)(Port = 32003))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = D12)
    )
  )
```

Comment: I may not have been accurate or clear. I didn't mean hostname. I mean Service Identifier (TOTAL,  FMAX, DELUCA)

Comment: There may not be a good way to reliably get the Service Identifier without a full parse of the descriptions.  I don't see a good way to shortcut a grammar-based solution. The only reason my awk-based solution to finding the "HOST" value  works is that I could make name/value pairs out of the descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a formal description of `tnsnames.ora`, so I'm kind of guessing at the format. Here's my stab at a script to do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=$1
tr '()' '\n\n' < input |
awk 'BEGIN {host=""; port=""}
    /[Hh][Oo][Ss][Tt]/ {host=$3}
    /[Pp][Oo][Rr][Tt]/ {port=$3}
    host && port {
        if (host == "'$HOST'") {print host, port}
        host=""; port=""
    }
'
```

That's GNU `awk` in a reasonably up-to-date Arch Linux install.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `grep` version which supports PCREs (like e.g. GNU `grep`), to list all the matches:

```
hostname="database.example.com.au"
< inputfile grep -Po "$hostname\)\(Port = \K[0-9]+"
```

To list only the first match:

```
hostname="database.example.com.au"
< inputfile grep -Po -m1 "$hostname\)\(Port = \K[0-9]+"
```

Using `sed`, to list all the matches:

```
< inputfile sed -n "s/.*$hostname)(Port = \([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p"
```

To list only the first match:

```
< inputfile sed -n "0,/$hostname/{s/.*$hostname)(Port = \([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p}"
```